# bash shortcut for stdin to come from /dev/null and both stdout and stderr to go to /dev/null

Tags: bash

I have a command that uses nohup to run a command in the background:

```
nohup bash myapp < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

My requirement is for:

- `stdin` to come from `/dev/null` and
- `stdout` to go to `/dev/null`
- `stderr` to go to `/dev/null`

**Question:** Is there a short cut in bash that allows me to shorten my command so that I only have to state /dev/null once, and not twice?

I've seen this [cheetsheet](http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-redirections-cheat-sheet.pdf), and I'm thinking that what I would like to do is not possible.

Comment: Maybe create an alias or a shell function.  You could also search the history: refer to _Searching_ in the READLINE section of the manual.

Comment: Instead of `> /dev/null 2>&1` you can use `&> /dev/null`. Should work from [tag:bash] 4 on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shortcut for redirecting both stdout and stderr to the same file is `&>` (you can also use `>&`, but `&>` is preferred).

You can also use a variable to hold the file so that you don't repeat it.

```
f=/dev/null nohup command < $f &> $f
```